# How do insert a separator bar between many groups on a Kendo UI Menu

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using the pure Razor style definition for a Kendo Menu:

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@(Html.Kendo().Menu()
    .Name("main-menu")
    .Items(items1 =>
        {
            items1.Add().Text("Home").Url(@Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
            items1.Add().Text("Movements").Items(subs =>
                {
                    subs.Add().Text("Import Data").Action("Import", "VehicleMovementBatch");
                    subs.Add().Text("View Movements");
                });
            items1.Add().Text("Presences");
            items1.Add().Text("Billing");            
            items1.Add().Text("Config").Items(items2 =>
                    {
                        items2.Add().Text("Pricing").Action("Index", "PriceRule");
                        items2.Add().Text("Users");
                    });                           
            items1.Add().Text("Control");
        })
)
```

I can find absolutely bloody nothing anywhere on all the internets, that even hints how to do do this properly. The closest I have is defining the DataSource in JavaScript object notation, with separators, and assigning it to the grid oj the client side at run time. This is definitely a good example of a case where can only pray to all the gods that the API isn't as superlatively inadequate as the documentation.

Comment: (For those curious how [awesome the API is](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/wrappers/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/MenuItemFactory).)

Comment: Really rich documentation there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is all you need to do. Figured it out on my own because I couldn't find an answer anywhere on the web.

```
items1.Add().Text("<hr/>").Encoded(false).Enabled(false);
```

Comment: I found that using `&nbsp;` worked even better - there was still a small gap in the border when I used `<hr/>`. The `Encoded` property is super-handy, though, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The < hr / > thing didn't work for me in kendo 2014.1.528

This does:

```
children.Add().Text("<div class='k-separator'></div>").Encoded(false).Enabled(false);
```

So an example would be:

```
items.Add().Text("Menu X").ImageUrl(Url.Content("~/Content/img/menux_16E.png"))
    .Items(children =>
     {
         children.Add().Text("Item 1").ImageUrl(Url.Content("~/Content/img/item1_16E.png"));
         children.Add().Text("<div class='k-separator'></div>").Encoded(false).Enabled(false);
         children.Add().Text("Item 3").ImageUrl(Url.Content("~/Content/img/item3_16E.png"));
     });
```

Comment: Additionally I set background color because the separator was not visible: "<div class='k-separator' style='background-color:#94c0d2;'></div>" I used it to most upper items (Items - not children) in vertical orientation menu.

Comment: Ok - yeah, my site is so very close to the basic Bootstrap colors that it wasn't an issue in my theme.

Answer (score 0):

To help anyone coming across this issue in the future, you can add a separator directly with the following:

```
items.Add().Separator(true);
```

This works since at least v2013.2.918, since that is what I am using.

Justin

Comment: At least today, this had no effect for me. 2019.3.1023

Answer (score 0):

I have v2016.3.914 and `items.Add().Separator(true);` creates an unwanted horizontal scrollbar on an RTL page.
[image]

I solved it using this:

```
inner.Add().Separator(true).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 99%;" });
```